# Limiting range of an element in a vector based on preceding element

Tags: r

I want to random add a random number between 1 and 15 to each element in my starting positions vector (a random draw for each element), and I never want any element to be within 4 or less of each other (eg if an element is = to 20 then I dont want the next element to be any lower than 25). Has what I've written accomplished that, and is there a nicer way?

```
 startingpositions <- c(seq(5, 110-15, 15),seq(115, 220-15, 15),seq(225, 330-15, 15),seq(335, 440-15, 15))
  positions <- c() 
  x <- 0
  for (j in startingpositions)
# for each element of my vector
  {   
sub.samples <- setdiff(1:15 + j, seq(x-4,x+4,1))
# create the list of numbers it's ok to draw from (based on x which is = to my previous element). Only draw from numbers 4> than x                  
x <- sample(sub.samples, 1)
# create new x for my current element from sub samples
positions <- c(positions,x)  
#add x to my positions vector
 }
```

Comment: Can you add comments to your code explaining what you expect your statements to be doing? It will then be easier to explain where you might be wrong.

Comment: ok, I've done that. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Declare `startingpositions` and then run a short loop along the following lines, that should work.

```
for(i in 1:length(startingpositions))
{
startingpositions[i] <- max(startingpositions[i] + round(runif(1, 1, 15),0), startingpositions[i-1] + 4)
}
```